# Allow user to run PHP-FPM without password using sudoers

Tags: centos, sudo, php5

I'm trying to make it so a user can reload PHP-FPM without needing a password everytime.

I've added the following to the /etc/sudoers file using *pkexec visudo*, and there are no syntax errors, but it is still not working, any ideas?

```
Defaults exempt_group=forge
User_Alias FORGE = forge
Cmnd_Alias FORGE_COMMANDS = /usr/sbin/service php-fpm *
FORGE ALL = (ALL) NOPASSWD: FORGE_COMMANDS
```

I've hunted everywhere and this seems to be a common problem of getting it to work, but each question doesn't seem to have an answer, or one that works for me.

Using CentOS 7.

Thanks.

---

When using sudo -u I get the following:

*==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to manage system services or units.
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:*

I can then proceed as normal, but the point is for forge to be able to do this without requiring authentication.

Comment: What happens when you manually run the command manually with sudo -u

Comment: @RamanSailopal see edit above.

Comment: If you run "sudo -u forge sudo /usr/sbin/service php-fpm" and you are still getting a password prompt, there is an error in your sudoers configuration

Answer (score 1):

Managed to get this working after additional hunting.

Turns out the addition to the *sudoers* file needed to be in the right place, not just at the bottom of the file where everyone apparently tells you to put it.

So after:

```
## Allows members of the users group to shutdown this system
# %users  localhost=/sbin/shutdown -h now
```

and before:

```
## Read drop-in files from /etc/sudoers.d (the # here does not mean a comment)
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

I put in:

```
## Allows forge to restart the php-fpm service
forge ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service php-fpm restart
```

Hopefully this will help a few people out, seems to be a lot of people out there having the same issue.

Just replace *forge* with the user you want to grant the permission too.